# External local json file to HTML table

Tags: javascript

Im trying to grap my data from my external local json file and display it in a html table, but im reciveing this error: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. im not sure whats the problem as im new to coding

this is my code

**varer.js**

```
let refresh = document.getElementById('refresh')
let list = document.getElementById('mytable');

refresh.addEventListener('click', async ()=> {
list.innerHTML = `
<tr>
<th>varer</th>
<th>pris</th>
<th>billede</th>
</tr>
`;

  await fetch('http://localhost:8200/varer/getproducts', {
  method: 'GET'
  })
  .then((res) => res.json())
  .then((res)=> {
    console.log(res)
    res.forEach((e) => {`
    <tr>
    <td>${e.varer}</td>
    <td>${e.pris}</td>
    <td><img src="${e.billede}" style="height:50px;width:50px;"</td>
    </tr>
    `;
      
    });
  
  });
  
})
```

**varer-controller.js**

```
 router.get("/getproducts", (req, res) =>{
    console.log(products)
    
    res.send(products)
    
   })
```

**varer.json**

```
[{"varer":"dd","pris":"ddd","billede":"","id":3},{"varer":"a","pris":"aaa","billede":"","id":30},{"varer":"sss","pris":"ssss","billede":"","id":8839},{"varer":"aa","pris":"aff","billede":"","id":715012}]
```

varer.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JSON Test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="module" src="varer.js"></script>
</body>
    <h1>Opret en vare</h1>
    <form id="form">
        <input placeholder="Varer" id="varer" />
        <input placeholder="pris" id="pris" />
        <input type="file" id="billede" name="img" accept="image/*">
        <input value="Submit" type="submit" id= "submit" />
           </form>
    <form id="delete">
      <input value="Slet vare" type="submit" />
    </form>
    <button id = "refresh">Refresh</button>
      <table id = "mytable">
        
      </table>
    <form id = "logout" action="http://localhost:8200/index.html">
      <input type="submit" value="Log ud"/>
  </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The `fetch` is not being awaited, and data is not defined inside the listener

Comment: i've done some changes but it still dosent work, can you help me a little bit more??@evolutionxbox

Comment: For starters, you're `fetch`ing some URL but not assigning the response to anything, e.g. `const jsonResponse = await fetch('....').then(res => res.json())`

Comment: You're also trying to navigate up some directories to your json file from within a browser script, which may or may not work depending on how your web page and surrounding files are served.

Comment: Also, put the table update code inside the callback of `readTextFile`. Otherwise `data` may never be defined

Comment: ive updated the code now and its better now, but get this error and it still not get displayed.Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client. thanks for the help

Comment: @MikkelNielsen Annoyingly, that's a different question.

Comment: You deleted the other question so I'm commenting here. You need to make sure that your backend isn't trying to send multiple replies. I assume you're using node and express, and the most likely reason for this error is that your route handler makes multiple `res.json()` or `res.send()` calls instead of only one. As for the logout issue, you need to chose *one* way to handle it: either a) after the logout fetch, have the server reply with JSON, then do `location = "/login";` on the *client* (in the callback where you are currently logging the reply)

Comment: Or b) use a redirect on the server, which means instead of doing `fetch` on the client-side, you need to use `location = "/logout"` so that replying with html is fine and the browser will actually navigate there.

Comment: i'm a bit new to programming, could you maybe show how you would implement it, as im pretty confused right now. THANKS for the help!